# Move through image table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this to work. I have a table of plots, and I want to do a fixed jump through each of the columns of a row.

This is a section of my table:

```
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>Third</td>
            <td>Fourth</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="r1">
            <td><div class="col1"><img src="1.bmp"></div></td>
            <td><div class="col2"><img src="2.bmp"></div></td>
            <td><div class="col3"><img src="3.bmp"></div></td>
            <td><div class="col4"><img src="4.bmp"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="r2">
            <td><div class="col1"><img src="3.bmp"></div></td>
            <td><div class="col2"><img src="1.bmp"></div></td>
            <td><div class="col3"><img src="2.bmp"></div></td>
            <td><div class="col4"><img src="4.bmp"></div></td>
        </tr>
```

I want to make it such that I press an arrow key (left/right) and go to the prev/next column in the row. When I press (up/down) or scroll (up/down), I want the page to jump to the next row of images. With every jump, I want the top left corner of the plots of align on the same spot on the doc.

I've tried to use stuff like:

```
var i = 1;
$(window).click(function() {
    $(window).scrollLeft($("r2:nth-child(" + i + ")").position().left);
    i++;
});
```

and

```
$('r2').scroll(function(){
    var left = $(this).offset().left,
    top = $(this).offset().top;
    window.scrollTo(0, top);
});
```

But I can't get it to work. I'm assuming that I need a suitable function to put into something like this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            //jump to plot on right if < 4
            break;
        case 38:
            //jump to plot above if not top row
            break;
        case 39:
            //jump to plot on left if > 1
            break;
       case 40:
            //jump to plot below if not last row
            break;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a period character, followed by the name of the every class like r2, for example:

```
$(".r2")
```

Comment: is there a way to make it more generic for every row?

Comment: Use something like this: $("." + var)